# How to Loop this program

Tags: c++

so I made this simple program using a tutorial I am following on *YouTube*, but the thing I wasn't shown is how to give the user the chance to give a new selection if the previous one wasn't valid.

The program is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "1. Search" << endl;
    cout << "2. Quit This Program" << endl;
    cout << "3. View Record" << endl;

    cout << "Enter Your Selection Please >   " << flush;

    int input;
    cin >> input;

    switch(input) {
    case 1:
        cout << "Searching..." << endl;
        break;

    case 2:
        cout << "Quitting This Program" << endl;
        break;

    case 3:
        cout << "Searching For Record For Viewing..." << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "That is not a valid option" << endl;
        cout << "Please choose a selection from the menu:" << endl;
    }

    return 0;


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Need a loop to check if the choice is valid or not if it is valid break the loop, if it is invalid stay in the loop until it is valid.

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        bool selection = false;
        while(!selection){
            cout << "1. Search" << endl;
            cout << "2. Quit This Program" << endl;
            cout << "3. View Record" << endl;

            cout << "Enter Your Selection Please >   " << flush;


            int input;
            cin >> input;

            switch(input) {
            case 1:
                cout << "Searching..." << endl;
                selection = true;
                break;

            case 2:
                cout << "Quitting This Program" << endl;
                selection = true;
                break;

            case 3:
                cout << "Searching For Record For Viewing..." << endl;
                selection = true;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "That is not a valid option" << endl;
                cout << "Please choose a selection from the menu:" << endl;
            }
        }

        return 0;


    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't a more failsafe approach be to set `selection` on `true` before the `switch` and only set it to `false` in the `default` case? Now you have to remember to do this in every `case`.

Comment: Yes a selection on true would actually be better as it would require less maintenance, it might be a little more confusing for a beginner though...

Comment: This would be an example for do while loop where we print choices atleast 1 time.

Comment: You could but the do while just results in extra redundant code if the solution CommuSoft suggested was in place the do while loop would be more appropriate. This solution already already prints choices at least 1 time ;)

Answer (score 2):

That's a good use case of the `do`-`while` loop:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "1. Search" << endl;
    cout << "2. Quit This Program" << endl;
    cout << "3. View Record" << endl;

    cout << "Enter Your Selection Please >   " << flush;

    int input = -1;
    bool valid = false;
    do {
        cin >> input;
        valid = (cin >= 0 && valid <= 3);
        if(!valid) {
            cout << "Please try again..." << endl;
        }
    } while(!valid);

    switch(input) {
    case 1:
        cout << "Searching..." << endl;
        break;

    case 2:
        cout << "Quitting This Program" << endl;
        break;

    case 3:
        cout << "Searching For Record For Viewing..." << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "That is not a valid option" << endl;
        cout << "Please choose a selection from the menu:" << endl;
    }

    return 0;


}
```

The advantage of use a `do`-`while` is that the validation is centered on the top and thus compact. The disadvantage of this approach that the validation is centered at the top and you thus more or less duplicate the procedure with the options: if you add a new option, you will have to modify the validation process as well.

Comment: You probably want `while(!valid)`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "1. Search" << endl;
    cout << "2. Quit This Program" << endl;
    cout << "3. View Record" << endl;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter Your Selection Please >   " << flush;

        int input;
        cin >> input;

        switch(input) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Searching..." << endl;
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "Quitting This Program" << endl;
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "Searching For Record For Viewing..." << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "That is not a valid option" << endl;
            cout << "Please choose a selection from the menu:" << endl;
        }while(input != 2)

    }

    return 0;


}
```